# White space on top of my website caused by mysterious double quotes

Tags: html, space, double-quotes

I have this simple html :

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i try this file, it will always add me a double quote after the body block. I don't understand why. (see the firebug sample below).

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        "

        "
        <div id="container" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is still present if i delete any line break / space / ... 
Absolutely no CSS is involved, you get the entire code here, no additions are present in my own code.

EDIT : It seems like the problem only occurs with google chrome , not firefox or IE.

EDIT 2 : I tried with a fresh installation of Chrome Canary, i still have these quotes added. I really start to think that my host is adding theses.

EDIT 3 : Here the screenshots with/without the quote, made on a page with a menu.

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

WITH THE QUOTES (don't mind the huge black line behind, it's just the background) :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/43/1414154337-with.png

WITHOUT THE QUOTES :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/43/1414154337-without.png

Comment: try to remove all between `<body>` and `<div>` like `<body><div>`

Comment: I said i already had deleted any line break and space, it will just put ( "" ) after the body, which will cause a white space as well.

Comment: Are you actually seeing the quotes on your page, or are those merely present in the DOM inspector, representing an empty text block?

Comment: They are present only in the inspector, i can't see them in the page. But they are causing a mysterious space between the div and the top of the page. When i delete them from the inspector, the space disappear.

Comment: How is the file delivered? Any webserver?

Comment: The file is on a server hosted by OVH, in a sub directory of a wordpress theme.

EDIT : I just noticed the quotes only appear in chrome, not in firefox.

Comment: Whitespace shouldn't have any influence on the rendering of elements and spaces between them. Sure you're not dealing with whitespace caused by margins somewhere?

Comment: i'm 100% certain, because no css is involved, and when i delete these quotes, the white spaces disappears.

Comment: Are you copy this html from somewhere or not?

Comment: No, this is an original file.

Comment: This is just the inspector quoting the textual content of the element

Comment: But why does it affect the content in my page ? As i said, it's deforming my design and when i delete it from the inspector it's back to the normal

Comment: Are you using any AddOns?

Comment: I'm using AdBlock / Firebug / Quick Javascript Switcher / Add custom favicon / Hide Images / Awesome reload all buttons.

I'll check if deactivating them resolve that.

Comment: Could it be, and this is a complete guess because I use neither Wordpress or AdBlock, but your theme has been infected and is delivering ads, AdBlock is kicking in, but not removing the space the ad took up?

Comment: Sadly, AdBlock is turned off on my domain. Plus i tried this page on a fresh installation of chrome, so no plugin are interfering with the content.

Comment: I noticed that converting the html files encoding to UTF8 wBOM and EOL to unix solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Has [peppelauro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2962588/peppelauro) said in comments, try to *convert the encoding to UTF8*. If it does not works try adding *unix EOL*. I had this issue and it solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened was like I `json_encoded` some empty text, so it was showing `""` in the page, I understood after deeply debugging my code.